# hello im trying to get the bot to respond with "Given User is already muted"

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to get the bot to respond with "Given User is already muted" but when I mute someone who is already muted, it just responds saying I have muted the user.

I also would like to integrate:

```js
if (member.roles.highest.position >= message.member.roles.highest.position)
      return message.channel.send('You cannot mute someone with an equal or higher role')
```

But when I try to, I get this error:

**if (member.roles.highest.position >= message.member.roles.highest.position)**
^

**ReferenceError: member is not defined**

AND

**Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined**

```js
 module.exports = {
  name: 'mute',
  description: "This mutes a member",
  execute(message, args){
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) {
      return message.channel.send("Sorry but you do not have permission to mute anyone" );
    }

    if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) {
      return message.channel.send("I do not have permission to manage roles.");
    }
    const user = message.mentions.members.first();

    if (!user) {
      return message.channel.send("Please mention the member to who you want to mute");
    }

    if(user.id ===message.author.id) {
    return message.channel.send("you can not mute yourself");
  }
  let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")

  if(!reason) {
    return message.channel.send("Please Give the reason to mute the member");

  }

  //Mute ROLE
    let muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === "Muted")
    let mainrole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === "Verified")

    if(!muterole) {
    return message.channel.send("This server does not have role with name `Muted`")
  
    }
      
    if(user.roles.cache.has(muterole)) {
      return message.channel.send("Given User is already muted")
    }

    user.roles.remove(mainrole)
    user.roles.add(muterole)
    
    message.channel.send(`You muted **${message.mentions.users.first().username}** Muted by:<@${message.author.id}>  For \`${reason}\``)
    
    user.send(`You are muted in **${message.guild.name}**,For \`${reason}\``)

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you defined `user` as the variable for the "member" that you want to target with the mute, rather than a variable `member` (which your roles comparison code checks).

Your role checking code can be used like this:

```js
const user = message.mentions.members.first();
if (!user) {
  return message.channel.send("Please mention the member to who you want to mute");
}

// ... Other checks here

// Compared after `user` is defined, and undefined check is done
if (user.roles.highest.position >= message.member.roles.highest.position) {
  return message.channel.send('You cannot mute someone with an equal or higher role');
}
```

Note that I use `user.roles.highest.position` instead of `member.roles.highest.position`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply the `if (user.roles.highest.position >= message.member.roles.highest.position) {
  return message.channel.send('You cannot mute someone with an equal or higher role');
} `
 but the 
`const user = message.mentions.members.first();
if (!user) {
  return message.channel.send("Please mention the member to who you want to mute");
}`  seems to do the same thing (responding with You muted )

Comment: The second block of code (the comparison) is meant to be what you add. The previous block is the same as what you have already. You should add the comparison block after that, so that it checks the target user's roles.

Comment: oh no that works i just mean that the `const user = message.mentions.members.first(); if (!user) {   return message.channel.send("Please mention the member to who you want to mute"); }` seems to do the same thing (responding with You muted )